# select file input ng-change never triggers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So the file input opens up fine and I can choose a file. I also now that the file upload works and that it binds a file. But the ng-change event is never triggered.

```
<img class="profile-pic" ng-click="addHeaderImage()" ng-src="{{applyform.UseProfilePic}}"/>
<input type="file" ng-change="uploadHeader()" style="display: none" id="headerinput" ngf-select ng-model="file" ngf-multiple="false"/>

$scope.addHeaderImage = function () {
    document.getElementById("headerinput").click();
}

$scope.uploadHeader = function () {
    //$scope.loading = true;
    var file = document.getElementById("headerinput").files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    console.log("TJAABAB");
    reader.addEventListener("load",
        function () {
            //item.Image = reader.result;
            console.log("UPLOAD");
            console.log(reader.result);
            $scope.$apply();
            //$scope.updateQuoteHeader(item);
            //$scope.loading = false;
        },
        false);
    if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

so the function upload header is never triggered when I choose a file. Why is that?

Comment: `ng-change` triggers the function whenever value of `ng-model` changes. In your case `file` is in your input's `ng-model` and which is not a `$scope` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ng-change, try onchange:

```
<input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadHeader()" style="display: none" id="headerinput" ngf-select ng-model="file" ngf-multiple="false"/>
```